# Mouseover event for UL

Tags: css, image, mouseevent, mouseover, imagesource

I am trying to do an image change for a mouseover, in a ul navigation. I can't seem to try to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
ul#nav {
width: 940px; list-style: none; overflow: hidden; margin: -134px auto 25px auto;}

ul#nav li {width: 126px; height: 33px; float: left; padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    font-weight: bold; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; }




    ul#nav li:nth-child(1) {
        margin: 0 60px 0 0;

    }
    ul#nav li:nth-child(2) {
        margin: 0 316px 0 0;
    }
    ul#nav li:nth-child(3) {
        margin: 0 60px 0 0;
    }
    ul#nav li:nth-child(4) {
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul#nav li a {
        color: white; text-decoration: none;
    }
        ul#nav li a:hover {
            color: #660066;
        }
```

basically where I have "home" "about" "portfolio" and "contact" I want to replace with an image that then does a mouseover to a different image, is this possible???

Answer (score 1):

Without javascript, you're going to have to use the `background` css attribute, and then use the `:hover` pseudoclass to change the image source.

[This website](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/02/backgrounds-in-css-everything-you-need-to-know/) gives a fairly comprehensive overview of using the background attribute.

Basically it will be something like:

```
#nav li {
    background: url(images/image1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#nav li:hover {
    background-image: url(images/image2.png);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want a js solution for a simple image swap? The CSS solution provided does exactly what you asked for.